# Silverlight AutoCompleteBox

Tags: silverlight, autocompletebox

Does anyone know how to drop down the AutoCompleteBox to see all the values without guessing at an entry and starting typing.

I know I could use a ComboBox but on a data entry form where a user needs to enter lots of information it is preferable for the user to pick up the mouse as little as possible and so therefore I wanted to use the AutoCompleteBox. However, in smaller lists it is also useful to quickly be reminded of the choices which you could do in a combo with the up/down arrow.

I have seen some examples of combining the two controls' functionality into one and I may go this way but wondered if there is a simpler way.

Comment: How big is your small list? E.g. If you only have a dozen or so options - say months of the year... Then a regular drop down select list is likely more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

When I did this I had an autocomplete box on top of a combobox that were both bound to the same value, with the autocomplete box having a larger right margin so you could see the combobox arrow. Then I created a got focus event that opens the list of results and I set the MinimumPrefixLength to 0 so it would search with nothing typed in.

**XAML**

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" MinimumPrefixLength="0" GotFocus="AutoComplete_GotFocus" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void AutoComplete_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     AutoCompleteBox box = (AutoCompleteBox)sender;
     box.IsDropDownOpen = true;           
}
```